# How to stop a component from setting state before the data fetching?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a page and that page has two components. I am fetching the data from root component and passing data to child component using `react-redux`. I tried to set the fetched data to a  state variable that is in child component but it sets data before the fetch is complete in the root component. So, I am getting blank object.

```js
// child component
const [myData, setMyData] = useState<any>(null);
  const data = useSelector((state: { value: any }) => state.value);

  useEffect(() => {
    setMyData(data);
  }, []);
```

```js
// parent component

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        dispatch(setData(data));
      });

  }, []);
```

You can check the whole codebase : https://github.com/Sadiq1029/weather

Can someone help?

Comment: This is normal. React should re-render the child component when the state changes. The child component needs to be able to gracefully handle the situation where the value is not yet set, _or_ the parent component could conditionally omit the child component until the data is fetched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if `data` is not null then update your child state

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (data) setMyData(data);
}, [data ]);
```

**data.ts**

```
import { createSlice, createSelector } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const dataSlice = createSlice({
  name: "data",
  initialState: { value: null },
  reducers: {
    setData: (state, action) => {
      state.value = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { setData } = dataSlice.actions;

const selectDataSlice = (state: any) => state.data

export const selectValue = createSelector(selectDataSlice, (state) => state.value)

export default dataSlice.reducer;
```

**Background.tsx**

```
import { Container, Flex, Text } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import type { NextPage } from "next";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { selectValue } from "../../states/data";

const Background: NextPage = () => {
  const [myData, setMyData] = useState<any>(null);
  const data = useSelector(selectValue);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      setMyData(data);
    }
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <Flex
      minW="100vw"
      minH="100vh"
      alignItems="flex-end"
      style={{
        background: `url('/images/background.jpg') center no-repeat`,
        backgroundSize: "cover",
      }}
    >
      <Flex id="stats" m="8" flexDirection="column" color="white">
        <Text fontSize="xl" fontWeight="hairline">
          {myData ? myData.name : ""}
          {/* {data ? data.name : "hi"}, {data ? data.sys.country : "_"} */}
        </Text>
        <Text fontWeight="bold" fontSize="8xl">
          {/* {data ? Math.round(data.main.temp) : "0"}&deg;C */}
        </Text>
        {/* <Text>{data ? data.weather[0].main : ""}</Text> */}
      </Flex>
    </Flex>
  );
};

export default Background;
```

Comment: useSelector returns before the fetch resolves so checking data within useEffect is not useful

Comment: @SadiqurRahman Yes it is useful. The `useEffect` handler should fire _again_ when the value of `data` changes.

Comment: you have to set the default value in redux to null

Comment: check my repo if you can figure out the problem

Comment: https://github.com/Sadiq1029/weather

Comment: @SadiqurRahman your code is not working because you did not create a right selector, i have updated my answer

Comment: still getting null

Comment: can you make a pull request to my github? maybe I am doing something wrong

Comment: @SadiqurRahman i can not push code to your repo. I have posted  full code, you can check